# How can I do IOException.class in scala with junit?

Tags: scala, junit

I wrote this unit test in scala:

```
@Test(expected = Class[IOException].getClass)
def tryToConvertWhenFileAlreadyExistsTest(): Unit = {
  CsvToParquetConverter.convertAndSaveAsANewFile(exceptionalArgumentMap)
}
```

expected should be `Class[_ <: Throwable]`

but could not compile it, the errors that I get are:

```
Error:(115, 20) class java.lang.Class is not a value
  @Test(expected = Class[IOException].getClass)
```

and

```
Error:(115, 39) annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: 
Class[IOException].<getClass: error>
  @Test(expected = Class[IOException].getClass)
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: The title it's unclear. I don't know anything about Scala but probably you wanted the class "getClass()" instead of "getClass". Or maybe you needed an attribute of that given class, like the name . Figure out what you wanted to do, reformulate the question, and take a look at the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--

Comment: @ElMesa, no, in scala you can do "getClass" without parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that I should have done `classOf[IOException]`.